# python duplicate values and key ​in multiple dictionary rearrange into single dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a list of dict like this

```
list_1 = [{'id': '123', 'name': {'new': 'kevin'}},

          {'id': '123', 'name': {'old': 'alan'}},

         {'id': '456', 'name': {'new': 'jason'}},

          {'id': '456', 'name': {'old': 'jack'}}]
```

But I want to merge the same values ​​together using something function

The desired output is as follows

```
list_1 = somethingfunction()

output:

{'id': '123', 'name': {'new': 'kevin','old': 'alan'}}

{'id': '456', 'name': {'new': 'jason','old': 'jack'}}
```

Don't know if there is any function that can quickly merge the same values and key ​​together

Comment: I wonder why you think you'd need a Pandas function in the first place...

Comment: Are you expecting a DataFrame as results? why pandas?

Comment: Are you sure you want a list at all? It really looks like a dictionary where "id" is the key...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint


def merge_group(group: list[dict]) -> dict:
    """
    Merge a group of dicts into a single dict.

    First-level nested dicts are merged, other values replace previous values.
    """
    output = None
    for item in group:
        if output is None:
            # First item, (shallow-)copy it as-is.
            output = item.copy()
            continue
        for key, value in item.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):  # merge nested dicts (one level deep)
                output[key].update(value)
            else:  # replace other values
                output[key] = value
    return output


def merge_by_key(dicts: list[dict], key: str, group_merger=merge_group) -> list[dict]:
    """
    Group a list of dicts given a key, then merge the groups using the group_merger function.
    """
    groups = defaultdict(list)
    for item in dicts:
        groups[item[key]].append(item)
    return [group_merger(group) for group in groups.values()]


list_1 = [
    {"id": "123", "name": {"new": "kevin"}},
    {"id": "123", "name": {"old": "alan"}, "color": "purple"},
    {"id": "456", "name": {"new": "jason"}},
    {"id": "456", "name": {"old": "jack"}},
]
pprint(merge_by_key(list_1, "id"))
```

The output is

```
[
  {'color': 'purple', 'id': '123', 'name': {'new': 'kevin', 'old': 'alan'}},
  {'id': '456', 'name': {'new': 'jason', 'old': 'jack'}}
]
```

Comment: Just curious, why many people use the keyword `input` as a local variable?

Comment: @QuangHoang Because it literally is the input for the function, and I don't expect that function to need the global `input()` function to prompt anything from the user. Sure, it could be `dicts` too.

Comment: I know it's safe to do so, at least here. Plus, `input()` is rarely used in practical Python anyway. I just think that it's a bad practice, yet many think otherwise. It's just really strange seeing a (colored) keyword where it shouldn't be.

Comment: @QuangHoang Well, replaced it with `dicts` for cleanliness :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to group by id and merge names:

```py
import pandas as pd
list_1 = [{'id': '123', 'name': {'new': 'kevin'}},
          {'id': '123', 'name': {'old': 'alan'}},
          {'id': '456', 'name': {'new': 'jason'}},
          {'id': '456', 'name': {'old': 'jack'}}]
groupById = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(list_1)
for index, group in df.groupby('id'):
    for (id, name) in group.values:
        if(id in groupById):
            groupById[id].append(name)
        else:
            groupById[id] = [name]
            
print(groupById)
"""
{
"123": [
    {
        "new": "kevin"
    },
    {
        "old": "alan"
    }
],
"456": [
    {
        "new": "jason"
    },
    {
        "old": "jack"
    }
]
}
"""
output = [{'id': id, 'names': {list(name.keys())[0]:list(name.values())[0] for name in names}}
          for id, names in groupById.items()]

print(output)

"""
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "names": {
            "new": "kevin",
            "old": "alan"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "456",
        "names": {
            "new": "jason",
            "old": "jack"
        }
    }
]
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.9 you could use [Union Operator](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/) to create a dictionary with the data and than convert it back to list format

```
dic = {}
for d in list_1:
    dic[d['id']] = dic.get(d['id'], {}) | d['name']
print(dic) # {'123': {'new': 'kevin', 'old': 'alan'}, '456': {'new': 'jason', 'old': 'jack'}}    

lst = [{'id': id, 'name': name} for id, name in dic.items()]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
[{'id': '123', 'name': {'new': 'kevin', 'old': 'alan'}}, {'id': '456', 'name': {'new': 'jason', 'old': 'jack'}}]
```